# jboss-eap-5.1 heap out of memory

Tags: jboss, threadpool

My system run out of memory sometimes. I can see bellow error in logs every time when system is running out of heap memory

```
Maximum number of threads (200) created for connector with address abc.com/192.168.1.45 and port 8080
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss is crashing due to a high number of threads created. When it tries to create a new one, the application stops responding and starts to shutdown the application server.

Increasing the `maxThreads` parameter will resolve the issue. Do this incrementally; raising the value of `maxThreads` too much can result in performance problems such as:

- High memory usage
- General slowness due to the JVM being forced to context switch
  between many threads frequently

To increase `maxThreads` edit in `JBOSS_EAP_DIST/jboss-as/server/PROFILE/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml`

```
<!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
   connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="3000" 
   minSpareThreads="2000" maxKeepAliveRequests="-1" />
```

see also: [Performance Tuning Guide - Chapter 2. Connectors](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/chap-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Connectors.html#sect-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Java_IO_Connector-Tuning_the_thread_pool)

Comment: Could that be the reason for system to run out of memory?

Comment: This is not a memory problem, but an `threadpool` resource problem. You are running out of maxthreads. Maybe the `OutOfMemory` exception should have been named OutOfResources in this case. The `threadpool` cannot provide the resource you need.